# Veracode, Debug Symbols, and XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, veracode

I'm attempting to have an iOS application scanned by Veracode: an application security platform. In order for them to scan an .IPA, the .IPA needs to contain debug symbols.

For the Archive build-configuration and project/target being used, I've specified:

- Generate Debug Symbols : YES
- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy : NO
- Dead Code Stripping : NO
- Symbols Hidden By Default : NO
- Strip Linked Product : NO

Yet, Veracode still gives me the following error when submitting the .IPA:

*Primary Files Compiled without Debug Symbols - 1 File*

Is there another step I need to take to create debug symbols, perhaps wrt archiving?

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, got this working, but one change in the settings i did different to what you did, Dead Code Stripping : YES

Thanks @skmathu!!!

Comment: in Xcode 8.3.2 i don't see all above properties. i see only 'Strip Linked Product' and 'Strip Debug Symbols' During Copy properties in both target and project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by following the veracode instructions below. It basically tells you to manually create archive package, move the .app and .app.sym folders to a new location and then rename the zip file to an ipa.

From Veracode Help Center:

"Because Xcode does not create .IPA packages that contain DSYM information, you must create the package yourself. Xcode dynamically creates a folder to contain the .app and .app.dsym files. There is no definite path to this folder, but you can search the folder after you build your application. To do this, open Xcode and click Products on the left side of the window. Right-click the .app file, and select Reveal in Finder, which takes you to the folder where the .app and .app.dsym files are located. Once you have located the DSYM information, you can package your compiled iOS application as follows:

1. Select the .app and .app.dSYM folders for your application.
2. Copy both folders into a folder called *Payload*. Note: the folder name
   must be capitalized.
3. Create a zip archive containing the *Payload*
   folder. You can do this on a Mac by selecting the Payload folder and
   choosing Compress    from the context menu, or by using the
   zip-compatible archiving    utility of your choice.
4. Change the extension of the resulting archive to .ipa.
5. Upload this archive to the Veracode application profile.
   "